# Finding the area of a triangle from vertices? Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, volume

I pretty much did this problem, but I failed to get the few last blanks where they ask the area. Its confusing, they say its half the volume of matrix (u v w) in the start of the question. which means half the determinant, which is 66/2 = 33. But then at the very end, they give us a new formular hat V = 2*A*mag(W). I don't really see how they get A = 3sqrt(11)
Help me out;

Since the words are small, its better to view question on this webpage;

http://oi57.tinypic.com/1y4ti8.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but not in the form they expected. It looks like you have $33\sqrt{1/11}$, but

\begin{align*}&=3*11*\sqrt{1/11} \\
&= 3 \sqrt{11^2/11} \\
&= 3 \sqrt{11} \end{align*}

Comment: So it's an answer Jim, but not as they know it.